# AttributeError: 'GaussianNB' object has no attribute 'var_'

Tags: python

I am working on a python project and stuck on this
program is complied successfully. It gives error when i clicked "submit" after filling the required details.
using following libraries:
numpy, flask, pickle, Pandas, Matplotlib

i tried looking for solution but couldn't find one. Here's a similar question:- ['GaussianNB' object has no attribute 'var_' when I'm using pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71738828/gaussiannb-object-has-no-attribute-var-when-im-using-pickle)

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1519, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1503, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "f:\Projects\Heart Disease Predictor\HeartDiseasesPredictor-master\main.py", line 31, in hello_world
    infProb = clf.predict_proba([enter])
  File "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 123, in predict_proba
    return np.exp(self.predict_log_proba(X))
  File "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 102, in predict_log_proba
    jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
  File "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 487, in _joint_log_likelihood      
    n_ij = -0.5 * np.sum(np.log(2.0 * np.pi * self.var_[i, :]))
AttributeError: 'GaussianNB' object has no attribute 'var_'
```

**Main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
app = Flask(__name__)

file = open('model.pkl','rb')
clf = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == "POST":
        myDict = request.form
        print(myDict)
        name = myDict['name']
        cp = int(myDict['cp'])
        trestbps = int(myDict['trestbps'])
        sex = int(myDict['sex'])
        age = int(myDict['age'])
        fbs= int(myDict['fbs'])
        chol = int(myDict['chol'])
        restecg = int(myDict['restecg'])
        slope = int(myDict['slope'])
        ca = int(myDict['ca'])
        thalach = int(myDict['thalach'])
        exang = int(myDict['exang'])
        oldpeak = float(myDict['oldpeak'])
        thal = int(myDict['thal'])
        print(myDict)
        enter = [age,sex,cp,trestbps,chol,fbs,restecg,thalach,exang,oldpeak,slope,ca,thal]
        print(enter)
        infProb = clf.predict_proba([enter])
        x = infProb[0][1]*100
        return render_template('show.html',uname=name,inf = int(x))
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**my_trainging.py**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pickle

dataset = pd.read_csv('heart.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

#Naive Bayes Classifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
classifier = GaussianNB()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

infProb = classifier.predict_proba([[58,1,2,140,211,1,0,165,0,0,2,0,2]])
print(infProb[0][1]*100)

#creating the file to save the model
file = open('model.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(classifier, file)
file.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the `heart.csv` file if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is being generated with `sckikit-learn` version 0.24.2 or less and it's being read by a `scikit-learn` version 1.0.0 or higher. There is an [API change](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v1.0.html#sklearn-naive-bayes) that renamed `sigma_` to `var_` between those versions.

To fix it you should generate the model and read it later with the same version of `scikit-learn`

Comment: Thanks @lepsch for the help. My program ran without any error.